# Add two image into 2 layers in android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to do an app like photoshop, I want to add 2 image into 2 layers, and after that, I can eraser the top layer to make it transparent and see the bottom layers.

Please help me on this issue.

Thanks

Comment: then use layout Visible property by setting it to GONE to disappear from view then again make it visible.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. But what I want is: I have 2 image, and I want to let them in 2 layers (like photoshop), after that I can erase a mall region in the top image and can view the bottom image corresponding with the region I erase.

Answer (score 0):

Please use LayerDrawable

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList

To hide partial part use Clip Layer

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Clip

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want totally hide the top layer, just a part of it. How can I do? And sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Edited the solution to add answer for your next question